# Find line of text in MsgBox with a string literal with VBA regex

Tags: regex, vba, code-analysis

I want to know if a line of code in a certain format exists in a workbook's modules, in this case a MsgBox with a string literal, by VBA regex.
`pattern1` is found, but `pattern2` is not found even when it exists in the module.

`Pattern1` matches MsgBox with string literals, **with** opening and closing parentheses( ) e.g.:

```vb
testString = MsgBox("Do you want to open our product page?", vbInformation + vbYesNoCancel, "myMessageBox")
testString = MsgBox("Do you want to open our product page?", vbYesNoCancel, "myMessageBox")
testString = MsgBox("Do you want to open our product page?", vbYesNoCancel)
testString = MsgBox("Do you want to open our product page?")
```

`Pattern2` matches MsgBox with string literals, **without** opening and closing parentheses( ), e.g.:

```vb
MsgBox "Do you want to open our product page?", vbInformation + vbYesNoCancel, "myMessageBox"
MsgBox "Do you want to open our product page?", vbInformation + vbYesNoCancel
MsgBox "Do you want to open our product page?"
```

```vb
' Matches strings in all VBA modules of the specified workbook
' Add a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" for early binding

Public Sub FindStringsInModules(ByVal objWorkbookToObfuscate As Workbook)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Dim lineNum As Long
    Dim lineText As String
    Dim newLineText As String
    
    ' Iterate over all VBA modules in the provided workbook
    For Each vbComp In objWorkbookToObfuscate.VBProject.VBComponents
        ' Process each line in the module
        Dim lineCount As Long
        lineCount = vbComp.codeModule.CountOfLines
        For lineNum = 1 To lineCount
            lineText = vbComp.codeModule.Lines(lineNum, 1)
            newLineText = MatchLine(lineText)
            vbComp.codeModule.ReplaceLine lineNum, newLineText
        Next lineNum
    Next vbComp
End Sub

Function MatchLine(ByVal lineText As String) As String
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Set regex = New RegExp
    Dim pattern1 As String
    Dim pattern2 As String
    Dim pattern3 As String

    ' Pattern 1: Matches MsgBox with string literals, with opening and closing parenthesis ( )
    pattern1 = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*)?MsgBox\s*\(\s*(""[^""]*"")(?:\s*,\s*[^,)]+(?:\s*\+\s*[^,)]+)*)?(?:\s*,\s*""[^""]*"")?\s*\)"
    ' Pattern 2: Matches MsgBox without parentheses, including additional parameters and concatenations
    pattern2 = "MsgBox\s+""""[^""""]*""""(?:\s*&\s*""""[^""""]*""""|[^""""])*(?:\s*,\s*[^,""""]+)*"
    pattern3 = "MsgBox\(""[^""]*""\)\s*"

    ' Combine patterns using alternation operator
    regex.Pattern = pattern1 & "|" & pattern2 & "|" & pattern3
    regex.Global = True
    regex.MultiLine = True

    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Set matches = regex.Execute(lineText)

    ' Process each match for potential transformation
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        Dim match As match
        For Each match In matches
            Dim literal As String
            literal = match.SubMatches(0)
            If literal = "" Then
               Debug.Print "lineText not catched:" & lineText
               'Stop
            End If
        Next match
    End If

    MatchLine = lineText
End Function
```

`match.SubMatches(0)` returns that `literal = ""` even though `matches.Count > 0`.

P.S. When testing against a string literal in VBA, the MsgBox line
needs to be enclosed in double quotes, with inner double quotes doubled, for example, `testString = "MsgBox ""Do you want to open our product page?"""`.
When testing against a line of VBA code (not as a string literal), the MsgBox line would appear as directly written in the code, for example, `MsgBox "Do you want to open our product page?"`.

Comment: You have a lot of optional components in the regex. Why does it turn you off that the first subgroup was an empty match? What is `match.Value`?

Comment: Thanks, `match.Value` is more suitable then `match.SubMatches(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.Test(Text)` returns true if there is a match.   Here is how I would refactor the code:

```
Sub ExampleUsage()
    Const Pattern1 As String = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*)?MsgBox\s*\(\s*(""[^""]*"")(?:\s*,\s*[^,)]+(?:\s*\+\s*[^,)]+)*)?(?:\s*,\s*""[^""]*"")?\s*\)"
    Const Pattern2 As String = "MsgBox\s+""""[^""""]*""""(?:\s*&\s*""""[^""""]*""""|[^""""])*(?:\s*,\s*[^,""""]+)*"
    Const Pattern3 As String = "MsgBox\(""[^""]*""\)\s*"
    Dim MasterPattern As String
    MasterPattern = Join(Pattern1, Pattern2, Pattern3)
    
    
    Const NewText As String = "MsgBox(""Sample Text"")"
    
    Dim Patterns() As Variant
    Patterns = Array(Pattern1, Pattern2, Pattern3)
    
    ReplaceMatchesInModule ThisWorkbook, NewText, MasterPattern
End Sub

Public Sub ReplaceMatchesInModule(ByVal objWorkbookToObfuscate As Workbook, NewText As String, Pattern As String)
    Rem Requires the reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility #.#" library
    Dim Component As VBComponent
    Dim CodeModule As CodeModule
    Dim lineNum As Long
    Dim lineText As String

    ' Iterate over all VBA modules in the provided workbook
    For Each vbComp In objWorkbookToObfuscate.VBProject.VBComponents
        ' Process each line in the module
        Dim lineCount As Long
        lineCount = Component.CodeModule.CountOfLines
        For lineNum = 1 To lineCount
            Set CodeModule = Component.CodeModule
            lineText = CodeModule.Lines(lineNum, 1)
            
            If RegExMatch(Pattern) Then
                CodeModule.ReplaceLine lineNum, NewText
            End If
        Next lineNum
    Next vbComp
End Sub

Public Function RegExMatch(Text As String, GlobalMatch As Boolean, Multiline As Boolean, ByRef Patterns() As Variant)
    Rem Requires the reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library
    Dim Regex As New RegExp
    Regex.Global = GlobalMatch
    Regex.Multiline = Multiline
    
    Dim Pattern As Variant
    For Each Pattern In Patterns
        If Regex.Test(Text) Then
            RegExMatch = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Testing Regex is tedious.  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a popular website for testing.

Expression:

(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*)?MsgBox\s*(\s*("[^"]*")(?:\s*,\s*[^,)]+(?:\s*+\s*[^,)]+)*)?(?:\s*,\s*"[^"]*")?\s*)|MsgBox\s+""[^""]*""(?:\s*&\s*""[^""]*""|[^""])*(?:\s*,\s*[^,""]+)*|MsgBox("[^"]*")\s*